# Windows Server - how to shrink partition on GPT disk from the front?

Tags: windows, partition, gpt, shrink

I'm looking for a way to shrink a partition on a GPT disk from the front on production servers.
With diskpart it's only possible to shrink the space from the end.
Ideally while running

Comment: Any of the usual tools can do this, but it requires being offline. The volume cannot be mounted/in use.

Comment: What are the usual tools? Something other as Gparted?
Do you know any know that will work portable within windows.
Unmount volume, shrink, remount volume?

Comment: There are a bazillion utilities that will do this. Google it. Partition utilities.

Comment: The list is very short:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software

And it's not clear if something from that list works portable within a booted windows

Comment: to be honestly this question is nearly offtopic due it leads to software suggestions. however I used paragon or easeus software for resize partition. remind to have a full backup of the current system before you start over